# setting Numpy array elements with a class object

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a class called `Tensor`

```py
import numpy as np

class Tensor:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = np.array(data)
```

and I'd like to set elements of a numpy array using `Tensor`:

```py
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]])
x[:,::2] = Tensor([[0,0],[1,1]])
```

but it results an error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

one workaround is to retrieve Tensor's data attribute: `x[:,::2] = Tensor([[0,0],[1,1]]).data`, but I'd like to know how to do it without manually retrieving anything, like when you can set values with a list or numpy array: `x[:,::2] = [[0,0],[1,1]]` or `x[:,::2] = np.array([[0,0],[1,1]])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy array objects all follow a protocol, as long as you implement `__array__` method, you can use the object as an array:

```
>>> class Tensor:
...     def __init__(self, data):
...         self.data = np.array(data)
...     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
...         return self.data    # self.data.astype(dtype, copy=False) maybe better
...
>>> x[:,::2] = Tensor([[0,0],[1,1]])
>>> x
array([[0, 2, 0, 4],
       [1, 3, 1, 1]])
```

Reference: [Writing custom array containers](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.dispatch.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works! BTW, what is the use of `dtype=None`? when I delete it it results a `TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. When do you have to specify a dtype? Thanks!

Comment: @Sam-gege This is the signature format required by numpy. Usually, different `dtype` expect to get arrays of corresponding data types.